# When should I use "deine" or "du"?

Tags: word-usage, usage

What is the difference between the statements:

> 1. Was ist deine Adresse?
> 2. Was ist du Adresse?

I am confused on the usage of *deine* vs *du*. Although the translator translates both to "What is your address?" in the above statements, the first statement sounds more convincing but I do not have any explanation!

Comment: The difference is that the first translates to *What is you**r** address* while the second translates to *What is you address*, which is obviously wrong in both English and German.

Comment: "Was hast Du für eine Adresse?" wäre die äquivalente Frage zu 1 mit Du. Man fragt aber auch statt 1 eher "Wie ist Deine Adresse". Wenn man 2 Zettel mit Adressen hätte, dann könnte man sie jmd. zeigen und fragen "Was ist *Deine* Adresse?"

Comment: @Robert: Sicher, dass sich Deine Bemerkung nicht verirrt hat?

Comment: @userunknown The OP cannot differentiate *du* from *deine*. I do not think that he understands your comment.

Comment: The difference is: #1 is correct, #2 is wrong.

Comment: @AdInfinitum probably you are right. I did not understand what userunknown meant to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Deine" (your) is the possessive form and modifies "Adresse."

"Du" (you) is nominative form, doesn't modify anything, and is out of place in the context of "Was ist die Adresse?"

Answer (score 2):

1. is correct, translating to "What is your address?"
2. is incorrect, literally translating to "What is you address?", so "deine" is the possessive pronoun of "du" and is used whenever the following noun ("Adresse") belongs to this person.